# Multiple background css images (one fixed and the other scroll) displays all as scroll

Tags: css

I have tried with these css and for some reason the second image doesn't display as fixed

```css
.background {
    background-image: url(../img/gradient.jpg), url(../img/sky.jpg);
    background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: cover, cover;    
}
```

Also tried this way

```css
.backgroundv2 {
    background-image: url(../img/gradient.jpg) cover no-repeat scroll, url(../img/sky.jpg) cover repeat fixed;  
}
```

Comment: Future readers: I'm not sure if there's a way to do what OP is asking, however an easy fix is to put the fixed background on a wrapper `<div>` and the scroll background on the inner `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

try with: `background-position`

i.e:
`background-position: right bottom, left top;`